# Why is Az powershell returning this error on a simple "show policy definition" command?

Tags: azure, powershell-core, azure-policy

```
    PS /Users/myname> echo $name
    Deploy - Configure Log Analytics extension to be enabled on Windows virtual machines
    
    PS /Users/myname>  az policy definition show --name $name
    (InvalidPolicyDefinitionName) The policy definition name 'Deploy - Configure Log Analytics extension to be enabled on Windows virtual machines' is invalid. The policy definition name length must not exceed '64' characters.
    Code: InvalidPolicyDefinitionName
    Message: The policy definition name 'Deploy - Configure Log Analytics extension to be enabled on Windows virtual machines' is invalid. The policy definition name length must not exceed '64' characters.
```

The maximum length for a policy definition is not 64, but 128, infact the policy actually exists in Azure so it was defined and accepted by Azure.
Why is pwsh complaining?

Comment: ok but this prevents from creating a policy with > 64 characters name, while from the portal there are already built in policies with that lenght name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if creating New Policy definition along with definition `Name` parameter value exceeds 64 characters.

I tried to create a Policy by using below command:

```
New-AzPolicyDefinition -Name 'VMPolicyDefinition' -DisplayName 'Deploy - Configure Log Analytics extension to be enabled on Windows virtual machines' -Policy '{"if":{"field":"type","equals":"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"},"then":{"effect":"deny"}}'
```

[image]

In the Portal, Policy got created successfully like below:

[image]

Policy Definition Resource Name will be like below:

[image]

**Note** that: The policy definition `Display Name` has length limit of 128 characters and policy Definition Resource `Name` has the limit of 64 characters.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Resource naming restrictions - Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftauthorization)

Comment: fine, and what about the "az policy definition show" command, which has no "display name " option?

Comment: `az policy definition show --name <policy name>` is the syntax. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az-policy-definition-show

Comment: problem is "show" command  has no "display name " option.
 (exiting built in policies have "name" parameter > 64 char) 
i guess they cannot be retrieved (showed) from pwsh
See here 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47264

Comment: Yeah, the GitHub issue confirms it.